# How to filter ng-repeat with multiples ng-models

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello I want to make a ng-repeat but filtering with multiples ng-models in AngularJS.

For example: If an user put text in 2 different inputs I want that filters by that 2 words.

```
<input type="text" name="" ng-model="buscar1">

<input type="text" name="" ng-model="buscar2">

<div ng-repeat="job in filteredJobs = (jobs | filter:buscar1 + buscar2)"></div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is a project in which I must filter by different inputs, I need my ng-repeat to show only those elements that match the ng-models buscar1 and buscar2 of my inputs